# Match function not matching number from formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

In excel, the match function is failing to find a match in a range that contains it.

Since we can't attach workbooks, create the MRE with the following steps:

1. A1=.99
2. B1=1-A1
3. C1=MATCH(.01,B1:B2,0)

For me, C1 is #NA.  Does it show that for you?  If so, why?  If not, can you think of why it would for me?

Tried:

1. Making new workbook
2. Testing if B1=.01 -> TRUE
3. Hardcoding B1=.01 -> Match works
4. Matching B1 to itself -> works
5. Matching B1 to a cell containing hardcoded .01 -> fails
6. Googling -> Tons of people that don't know that 0=exact match or forgot to check for whitespace in strings.
7. Changing A1 -> Very interestingly, fails for .9, .8, and .7, but works for .6 (finding .4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computers operate in base 2, not base 10, so when doing floating point arithmetic, there are some numbers that can not be represented, even if they seem perfectly fine in base 10. You are seeing 0.01, but Excel has actually calculated 0.0100000000000000000000x or something along those lines.

If you want to make your example work, try setting B1 to

```
=ROUND(1-A1,2)
```

Alternatively, if you know you just need two digits of decimal precision (assumed since you are matching to 0.01), you can just avoid the floating point all together by:

```
=(100-(100*A1))/100
```

Comment: I confirmed this is the correct solution. I assumed that formatting B column to use two decimal digit number format will correct this. THIS IS NOT the case. I think is because, when encountering a formula on a field, the `MATCH` function recalculates instead of taking the number presented to the user... if that makes any sense.

Comment: So, I can confirm that doing that works, but it works even when I put ROUND(1-A1,10000) and I doubt excel secretly has 10,000 digits of precision, so I think something else is going on.

Comment: Also, that doesn't explain why it works on everything I've tried where A1 in[0,.65] but not where A1 in [.66,1).

Comment: Excel might be doing something else when it works with round to 10000, I don't know what that is. But this is the issue, there's no other mystery. Open a python terminal and type 1-0.99, and you'll see the exact number it calculates. type round(1-0.99, 10000) and round(1-0.99, 2) and you'll see that in the python shell it works as you would expect. 
Also, try 1-0.65 and 1-0.66 and you'll se as well why some work and some others don't. 
Read about floating point imprecision, it's very interesting and if you are into programming at all, you are going to find this issue many times in the future

Comment: Ok, so the python terminal results are consistent with your explanation.  I'm curious why it works 0 to 0.65 but not above.  Also, why excel's ROUND function fixes it no matter the precision. And, why it doesn't display the imprecision no matter how many digits I show.  The more pressing question for me now is: do I have to add ROUND to everything in Excel to make it matchable or is there some setting or simpler fix to this "feature"?

Comment: Also, why does B1=.01 return TRUE?  Is MATCH(...,0) not checking for equality?

Comment: B1=.01 returns true because the imprecission is not there. Lookup IEEE-754 to understand the details. I've also added an alternative way to do it if you want to avoid the ROUND method. Also don't get confused by what is shown changing the number of digits, that's just the output format, not the internal representation.

Comment: I don't think I worded my question clearly.  B1 is still 1-A1, but set D1 to "=B1=.01" and D1 will show TRUE.

Comment: After some additional testing, I'm convinced that this answer is correct, so I moved my other questions about inconsistencies between MATCH and = to a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66140216/why-do-excel-match-and-return-different-results).