# Why do excel MATCH and "=" return different results?

Tags: excel, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

In a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66129480/match-function-not-matching-number-from-formula) it was determined that the MATCH error was being caused by floating point imprecision.  There were still seemingly inconsistent results from excel that exceeded the scope of the question.  Here are some:

1. MATCH(1-0.99,{0.01},0) -> #N/A
2. 1-0.99=0.01 -> TRUE
3. MATCH(ROUND(1-0.99,10000),{0.01},0) -> 1
4. MATCH(1+1E-100,{1},0) -> 1
5. ROUND(1E-100,1000)=0 -> FALSE

So MATCH thinks 1-.99 is not the same as 0.01 but "=" says they are.  Possibly MATCH is using higher precision, except that it does think ROUND(1-.99,10000) is 0.01.  Maybe MATCH has precision higher than 10,000 digits, but MATCH thinks 1+1E-100=1, so clearly not.  And maybe ROUND is secretly limited to 15 or something, so that ROUND(x,10000) is internally ROUND(x,15), except that ROUND(1E-100,1000)<>0.

So, what is excel doing under the hood to produce these unintuitive answers?
Bonus question: Is there a way to set MATCH to behave like "=" or to set everything to round to 15 digits? (I know you can set precision to displayed, but I don't want to have to always display 15 digits).

Comment: There is a difference between what is displayed in the cell and the numerical representation "under the hood". The correct answer to your questions in this post and in your previous post are in your accepted answer in the previous post. It all has to do with the binary representation of the number. The way to work with that is to use `ROUND` in your formulas. You can use the same or a different number of decimal digits to display as you use in `ROUND`.  But it's the `ROUND` in your formula that will drive your comparison accuracy.

Comment: This question is not about the displayed representation, but rather the apparent inconsistency between MATCH and = for determining equality.

Comment: I do understand the question, and the answer to your other post answered it. But for additional details you can learn more at [this site](https://newtonexcelbach.com/2012/01/07/comparing-floating-point-numbers/), [this site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/), and [this site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result)

Comment: I'm looking for something more specific than "It's floating point, read about it".  Presumably both "=" and MATCH deal with numbers as floats, so I still don't understand why there is a difference in their behavior.  None of the linked articles metions the MATCH function. If the explanations for the above 5 results are obvious to you from the other answer, feel free to leave an answer here spelling out how each occurs, for others who may not find it obvious.

Comment: I have not gone deep into the library/code implementation of `MATCH` and discovered why it is different from the other comparison methods. The times I have run into this situation (and several of these have caused serious issues to work around), I end up implementing a solution that achieves the result. I hope you can get someone who is familiar with the internal implementation of the libraries and implementation of the `MATCH` and other functions to answer your question.